# Stair-step crack question

Tags: cracks

I live in student housing where there is very poor maintenance of the building. This building looks like it was built cheaply (such as the walls being very very thin, and not having windows that you can open). Even though the building just turned three years old there are a number of problems with it already. One thing I am concerned about is a stair-step crack. From far away the crack doesn't look like much to the average person. But when I look closely I can see through it in three spots. This apartment is in Florida where there is a high water table. The wall is on the first floor of a 20 story building. The crack appears to have been patched over at one time but has reopened. A new apartment building was built right near here and I am thinking maybe it disturbed the wall.

I just wanted to get other people's opinions to see if I reach out to the authorities (wanted to make sure I am not overreacting). There are a number of things that concern me about this building (such as the parking garage often has water in it even when it isn't raining. I think the pool is leaking).

I uploaded some pictures here.

https://www.instagram.com/p/CyTMV2ILS6S/?img_index=1

https://www.instagram.com/p/Cyd5THPJ53T/

When I stand in front of the crack I can feel cold air from the other side and can even see through to the wall on the other side of this one.

Thank you for reading this.

Comment: Shoddy construction of a high-rise building - yup, sounds like Florida... https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Surfside_condominium_collapse

Comment: They also had issues with the pool leaking, and nearby construction. That has many of the residents here even more concerned. And the FIU bridge collapsed right outside of this apartment.

Comment: A stair step crack typically implies foundation settlement. The other with the less regular pattern looks like it could be settlement too. Out of curiosity I might look at the soils reports developed for the project and confirm that differential settlement was probable. If settlement is the root cause, then I would anticipate, at worst, nuisance damage. Doors sticking, windows not closing nicely. Stuff like that.

Comment: Your "see through to the wall on the other side of this one" is an odd thing to say. Are these parking spot partitions or something?

Comment: I know that pool chemicals make for corrosive electrical environments. I assume the same is true for pool chemicals, where their interaction with reinforcing steel sounds interesting. I've never researched it.

Comment: By seeing through the wall I mean that if I look through the cracks in the stair-step cracks I can see through the cracks. This is on the first floor of the building.

Comment: I can't prove that it is the pool that is leaking but it makes sense that that is what it is. I am trying to document things in case something happens. The managers of this building do not seem to care and residents are not happy here.

Comment: I would be ready to move out.  When building inspectors come, they will probably not want to take a chance that building will stay up and order everyone out.  You do have enough examples of what might happen nearby.

Comment: If you're really concerned, simply call the local building inspector's office and many an anonymous request for an inspection, calling out the items of concern. If you really want it to remain anonymous, use a public phone (there's got to be one _somewhere_ on campus). Let the building inspectors determine if there's an issue or not.

Comment: I am planning on moving out. I just wanted to start collecting evidence in case something happens after I move out. I have messaged some people who work for the county. The problem is that my city is really corrupt so I don't know who to trust.